# How to change variable name using textInput in a ShinyApp?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like the name of the variables to change according to a text typed in `textInput`.

For example, when I typed "Stack Overflow" in "A1" field, this name ("Stack Overflow") would appear as the new name, instead `conj1`.

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard", titleWidth = 300)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 300, 
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(text = "Simulador", tabName = "simulador1",icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  )

body <- dashboardBody(
  
  column(id = "c1", width = 12, 
         
         textInput(inputId = "ar1", label = "A 1", placeholder = "Digite")
    
  ), 
  
  column(id = "colsimul4", width = 12,
         
         textInput(inputId = "lvl1", value = 1,label = "Nível 1", placeholder = "Digite")
    
  ),
  
  column(width = 12, tableOutput(outputId = "new"))
  
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  fpred_1 <- function(x) {
    
    x
    
  }
  
  predattr1 <- reactive({
    fpred_1(x = input$ar1)
  })
  
  pred_1 <- reactive({
    fpred_1(x = input$lvl1)
  })
  
  output$new <- renderTable({
    isolate(expr = conj1 <- predattr1())
    experiment <- expand.grid(conj1 = c(pred_1()))
    isolate(expr = experiment)
  })
  
}

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like the name of the variables `conj` to be modified according to what is typed in the field `A1`

I tried this:

```
isolate(expr = conj1 <- predattr1())
```

But doesn't work.

For example, if I typed "Stack Overflow", this name appears instead of `conj1`.

The values ​​change normally, only the variable names do not.

**Edit**

I tried that too:

```
output$new <- renderTable({

  isolate(expr = conj1 <- predattr1())

  x <- names(predattr1())

  experiment <- expand.grid(
    
      colnames(x)[1] = c(pred_1())
    
  )

  expr = experiment

})
```

Nothing...

Comment: It would be easier to help if you removed most of the above code to provide a [minimal, reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) The keyword here is *minimal*: it's difficult to see what is going on with so many lines of code that are largely not crucial to producing the current issue.

Comment: If the uploaded answer(s) achieve what you want, feel free to accept although it is not required. If answer(s) do not achieve what you want, please let us know. Don't think you need the `isolate` calls, so I removed them. However, you can always add a "Push" button that will update everything that is `reactive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

################################################################################
# UI
################################################################################

# Header
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard", titleWidth = 300)

# Sidebar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 300,
                            sidebarMenu(menuItem(
                              text = "Simulador",
                              tabName = "simulador1",
                              icon = icon("dashboard")
                            )))

# Body
body <- dashboardBody(
  column(
    id = "c1",
    width = 12,
    
    # Text input 1
    textInput(
      inputId = "ar1",
      label = "A1",
      placeholder = "Digite"
    )
    
  ),
  
  column(
    id = "colsimul4",
    width = 12,
    
    # Text input 2
    textInput(
      inputId = "lvl1",
      value = 1,
      label = "Nível 1",
      placeholder = "Digite"
    )
    
  ),
  
  # Table appears below text inputs in same column/panel
  column(width = 12, tableOutput(outputId = "new"))
  
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

################################################################################
# Server
################################################################################

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  # Create table
  experiment <- reactive({
    df <- expand.grid(req(input$lvl1))
    colnames(df) <- req(input$ar1)
    return(df)
  })
  
  # Render table
  output$new <- renderTable({
    experiment()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```